# Connecting to P2P groups together in Wi-Fi direct

Tags: wifi, wifi-direct

I have a scenario of two P2P groups ,each with one AP-client pair.They are independent P2P groups.I am curious to know what will happen if the two P2P groups come close to each other?

Comment: Is it P2P or AP/Clients?

Comment: I meant two P2P groups, each with a GO and one corresponding client.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR;
The groups will not effect each other.**

The WiFi Direct specifications states that devices must be in the FIND phase in order to find more peers to connect to, and even if they were, they wouldn't try to connect unless they were running an app that told them to disconnect from their current group and connect to a new group if they find one.

Two group owner devices can connect to each other if that feature is supported in the particular implementation of Wi-Fi Direct on the devices you are using, and if it supported by the Wi-Fi chip on those devices. According to [this paper](http://hsc.com/Portals/0/Uploads/Articles/WFD_Technology_Whitepaper_v_1.7635035318321315728.pdf), it's possible for a device to  be a group owner in one group, and a client in another group by time-sharing the Wi-Fi interface:

> In order to act both as P2P Client and as  P2P GO the laptop will
>   typically alternate  between the two roles by time-sharing the Wi-Fi 
>   interface.

On the other hand, **it is impossible to have a group with two group owners.** The Wi-Fi direct groups will still be separate from each other, there will simply be a group owner in one that is a client in the other.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://www.digikey.com/us/en/techzone/wireless/resources/articles/Wi-Fi-Direct-adds-Peer-to-Peer-Capabilities.html)

> Some of the capabilities, such as concurrent P2P group and AP
>   connections, will add complexity to product designs at both the IC and
>   Wi-Fi subsystem levels. A product will have to maintain multiple MAC
>   entities to support concurrent operations and most likely will require
>   concurrent communications on multiple Wi-Fi channels. Clearly the
>   feature will be valuable, but will it be worth the extra cost required
>   to implement it? That’s up to the designer to decide. Over time, the
>   market use, or not, of those features will make that decision easier.

So as far as I understood basic mode is single p2p group per device and since device bound to one group it will not jump in immediately to another group.

Android Classes Reference can be find [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html)

Attempt of implementation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216085/wifi-direct-on-jellybean-wpa-supplicant-messed-up)

if device supports more then 1 group it will registered by 2nd group manager as available peer and then any member of group can TRY to connect to device. Device should have some WPS like security or for mobile phone popup dialog.

More on security from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct#Technical_description):

> Wi-Fi Direct essentially embeds a software access point ("Soft AP"),
>   into any device that must support Direct.[9] The soft AP provides a
>   version of Wi-Fi Protected Setup with its push-button or PIN-based
>   setup.
>
> When a device enters the range of the Wi-Fi Direct host, it can
>   connect to it, and then gather setup information using a Protected
>   Setup-style transfer.[9] Connection and setup is so simplified that
>   some suggest it may replace Bluetooth in some situations.[12]
>
> Soft APs can be as simple or as complex as the role requires. A
>   digital picture frame might provide only the most basic services
>   needed to allow digital cameras to connect and upload images. A smart
>   phone that allows data tethering might run a more complex soft AP that
>   adds the ability to bridge to the Internet. The standard also includes
>   WPA2 security and features to control access within corporate
>   networks.[9] Wi-Fi Direct-certified devices can connect one-to-one or
>   one-to-many and not all connected products need to be Wi-Fi
>   Direct-certified. One Wi-Fi Direct enabled device can connect to
>   legacy Wi-Fi certified devices.
>
> The Wi-Fi Direct certification program is developed and administered
>   by the Wi-Fi Alliance, the industry group that owns the "Wi-Fi"
>   trademark. The specification is available for purchase from the Wi-Fi
>   Alliance.[13]

Comment: So the presence of a P2P group does not have any influence on another P2P group ,when both the groups come close to each other?

Comment: I think its replacement for bluetooth just more powerful and anyhow require some kind of binding otherwise ur neighbor will watch fotos on your camera and print on your printer.

Comment: What happens if one P2P group wants to communicate with the other.Can a Go get connected to other GO?

Comment: Thanks for the links...but my doubt still persist:( Can a Go get connected to other GO?

Comment: Sorry for the confusing short hand. GO is Group Owner.It acts as a AP in a P2P group and is elected from the P2P devices through negotiation

Comment: Please read page N2 A Architecture in http://labs.netcom.it.uc3m.es/~agsaaved/papers/2012_camps_wircommag.pdf‎ They consider case of 2 P2P Networks. Well they not independent but seems it doesn't matter I guess.

Comment: Actually I m having hard time with three scenarios . First case is the two P2P groups coming close together .Second case is if one of the Group owner is suddenly turned off . What will the expected behaviour in these two cases?. And the last scenario is the one with the GO-GO communication,where I am not sure about such a possibility?

Comment: Second case is if one of the Group owner is suddenly turned off - Group is disbanded. The clients have to restablish the connection and one of the client becomes the group owner.

Comment: Consider looking at this patent about GO delegation : http://www.google.com/patents/EP2519071A2 But its probably not part of standard

Comment: That one was so helpul.I was able to clear the second and third cases.Now behind the first one. Kindly share any link which you think helpul to solve this issue.Thanks in advance.